# Is there any good websites that teaches datagram sockets use in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I want to program in Java some application that would use sockets, especially UDP sockets. Do you have by chance any good website where I can find some resources?

Comment: TCP is also sent as a datagram so don't confuse the meaning of that word

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [this web site](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html) yet?

You can always [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+udp) on Google.

Comment: google can give websites which teach java
However, google cannot tell which websites are good

Answer (score 1):

Here is one :-)

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-networking/udp-datagram-sockets.html